# Download large output pdf (>1 Gb) from Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I'm using Overleaf to merge several PDFs, and while it compiles, I can't download the result. Both in Chrome and Edge, the download stops as it comes to 1.0 Gb (out of 1.6, according to the download manager). Downloading other files of similar size, from other sites, work.

I managed a work-around: in a different project I imported the output of my merge project to the library, and from there it was possible to download (when downloaded, the file turned out to be 1.9 Gb). But is there a technical reason for why it wouldn't work to download the output directly?

The project I'm working on will eventually include more than just merging the files, so unfortunately suggestions like "use a different service to merge PDFs" or similar will not work. I need to include up towards 150-200 PDF files in one LaTeX document, and download the output which will be larger than 1 Gb.

Comment: If the pdfs that you are merging are also generated via LaTeX, I would recommend you look into including the individual `.tex` files and generating the larger pdf directly instead of merging. The size reduction is astonishing. In one case, my individual pdfs were 700MB, but got that down to 17MB by generating a smaller number of pdfs. There is a LOT of overhead that most likely won't get optimized when merging. Also, in case links (or other annotations) are important, they are complely lost during the merging process, but retained if you generate a single pdf directly.

Comment: Ask the overleaf support for help.

Comment: @PeterGrill no, they are scanned documents unfortunately. Generally a good tip, though, which I'll keep in mind in similar situations!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I'll do that!